# Format of mail-server PTR record in order it to be valid for spam filters?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

I am aware that lot of e-mail spam-filters will check the PTR record of the mail-server IP address. However, what are the exact requirements for this PTR record?

Is it enough if the PTR record is something like *2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.* if the IP address of my e-mail server is 192.0.2.1? In other words is it required that IP address has at least some kind of PTR record and the format of the PTR record doesn't matter?

Or is it required that the domain name part of the A record is present in PTR record? For example if the A record of my mail-server IP address is *mail.example.org* and domain name part of this record is *example.org*, then the PTR record has to be for example *hosts.example.org*, *mx.example.org*, *something.example.org*, etc?

Or is it required that A record and PTR record match? For example if the A record resolves to *mail.example.org*, then the PTR record needs to be exactly *mail.example.org* as well?

Last but not least, is it required that mail-server itself announces the PTR name(for example with *SMTP Service ready* message) and this has to match with the PTR record in DNS system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'format' of a PTR record.  It's a pretty straightforward and well-defined [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-12).

As for the name you put on the PTR record, you can pretty much pick anything you want as long as you can have a matching A record.

I think you misunderstand how an A record works; an A record is literally a name pointing to a number.  You can have as many A records pointing to the same IP address as you want.  You can have hosts.example.org, mx.example.org, something.example.org all pointing to 192.0.2.1.

What most spam filters check is that you have an A record that *matches* the PTR record.  You can only have one PTR record.  If you

So in your lists of hosts above, you can use any of them in the PTR as long as there is also a matching A record.